# How to produce both xml and json for a rest based service?

Tags: rest

I am trying to produce both xml and json from my rest service.

```
                 @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
```

However, when I try to use the service using curl/SOAPUI, I get back either xml or json depending on which is mentioned first. In simple words, only the first method is considered. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You probably should at least mention which tools you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this link out - [oracle docs for @Produces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrns/)

The spec says that it does indeed default to the first one if that is acceptable as specified by the media type on the request.  You should check your soapUI tool and see what headers you are sending.  If they are both being sent you will get a response with the first one listed in your @Produces annotation.